# Subtract a duration from a time field in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to subtract the lunch duration from a `time` value but I seems that I can't get it working. Following is the code I am using:

```
// get the values of the fields
var sStart = this.getField("StartTimeMonday").value;
var sEnd = this.getField("FinishTimeMonday").value;

// clear field as a default action
event.value = "";

// compute only if we have values
if (sStart != "" && sEnd != "") {

    // add a formatted date value to the time field values
    sStart = "1-Jan-1970 " + sStart;
    sEnd = "1-Jan-1970 " + sEnd;

    // convert the date time strings to date object
    var oStart = util.scand("d-mmm-yyyy h:MM tt", sStart);
    var oEnd = util.scand("d-mmm-yyyy h:MM tt", sEnd);

    // convert date object to milliseconds since 1-Jan-1970
    var nStart = oStart.getTime();
    var nEnd = oEnd.getTime();

    // compute the difference in milliseconds
    var nDiff = nEnd - nStart;

    // convert to seconds
    var nSeconds = Math.floor(nDiff / 1000);

    // compute the whole hours from the minutes
    var nHrs = Math.floor(nSeconds / 3600);

    // compute the remaining minutes
    var nMins = (nSeconds / 60) % 60;

    // set field value string to formatted time string
    event.value = nHrs + ":" + util.printf("%,202.0f", nMins);

}
```

A field containing a `time` value for the duration of lunchtime (in my timesheet) has to be subtracted from final value before displaying. For instance, in the sample below, the final value should be `11:30`.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: does 24 hour format support `AM/PM` ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi No. `MealTimeMonday` is in `HH:MM` format.

Comment: So if it is 24 hour format, why does it have AM/PM in the screenshot?

Comment: If I understand you, take a lock at my updated answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for the [Moment.JS](http://momentjs.com) lib, as vanilla JS is a big pain when it come to deal with date and time...

---

[edit]

If I understand your question, I think this is what you want :

```js
function f(){
  // get the values of the fields
  var sStart = document.getElementById("StartTimeMonday").innerHTML;
  var sEnd = document.getElementById("FinishTimeMonday").innerHTML;
  var sMeal = document.getElementById("MealTimeMonday").innerHTML;

    // convert the date time strings to date object
    var oStart = moment(sStart, "h:mm A");
    var oEnd = moment(sEnd, "h:mm A");

    // convert date object to seconds since 1-Jan-1970
    var nStart = oStart.format('X');
    var nEnd = oEnd.format('X');
    // just in seconds for this one
    var nMeal = moment.duration(sMeal);

    // compute the difference in seconds
    var oDiff = moment.duration(nEnd - nStart - nMeal.asSeconds(), 'seconds');
  
    // set field value string to formatted time string
    document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML =  oDiff.hours()+':'+oDiff.minutes();

}
```

```css
table { color: #333; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
td, th { border: 1px solid #CCC; height: 30px;}
th { background: #F3F3F3; font-weight: bold;}
td { background: #FAFAFA; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="">StartTime</th>
    <th id="">FinishTime</th>
    <th id="">MealTime</th>
    <th id="">Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="StartTimeMonday">6:00 AM</td>
    <td id="FinishTimeMonday">6:00 PM</td>
    <td id="MealTimeMonday">0:30</td>
    <td id="Total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="f()">run</button>
```

Comment: A plugin is a terrible recommendation for this problem. The op simply isn't subtracting the meal break from anything.

Comment: When I see `JS + date + format` I don't search any more, I go straight for Moment. I've wasted enough of my life trying to deal with date in vanilla JS... but if you submit a good answer you got my up ;)

Comment: The problem is logic not javascript data types. Moment will not help at all. There is no answer to this question other comments. OP requires more detail, i.e. correlation of shift length with lunch period. As it stands the logic is to subtract 30mins from shift length. So with an 8hr shift length, lunch would be at 0730hrs even though the shift only starts at 0600hrs. So missing a lot of detail.

Comment: I think you don't understand what OP want, but maybe it's me... ; I've add a snippet of what I think he want

Comment: You're right. I'm the one who misunderstood the logic. Given OP had already calculated minutes etc from start end, I figured they wanted something else. I still wouldn't take a dependency on moment.js just for this tho as per my answer.

Comment: @Blag Thanks for the answer and sorry for my late comment. Can I use your code for PDF forms in Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: @Bababarghi ô_O ho~ ; external Lib will be a problem I think (this is the kind of thing you need to add in the TAG of your post...); maybe try with [Rism answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33725818/5546267) in vanilla JS, you'll have more luck I think...

Answer (score 2):

Given you've already been able to calculate start and end times, you should be able to just continue with your logic as below:

It's unclear from the comments if you are using 24hrs format or not. If so the above is fine. If not you'll need another line in `getMinutes` to split out `am` or `pm` and add 12 if it is `pm`.

EDIT: Snippet below

```js
document.getElementById("btnStart").addEventListener('click', startRun);

var timeCardManager = (function() {
  function getMinutes(value, ampm) {
    var timeOffset = 0;
    var timeParts = value.split(':');
    if (ampm) timeOffset = value.split(' ')[1].charAt(0) == 'P' ? 12 : 0;
    return ((parseInt(timeParts[0]) + timeOffset) * 60) + parseInt(timeParts[1]);
  }

  function getShiftLength(startEl, endEl) {
    return getMinutes(endEl.innerHTML, true) - getMinutes(startEl.innerHTML, true);
  }

  function getBreaksLength(breaksElArr) {
    return breaksElArr.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + getMinutes(b.innerHTML)
    }, 0);
  }

  function getPaidShiftLength(start, end, breaks) {
    return getShiftLength(start, end) - getBreaksLength(breaks);
  }

  function formatMinutesTo24Hr(minutes) {
    var hrs = Math.floor(parseInt(minutes / 60));
    var mins = Math.floor(minutes % 60);
    return ("00" + hrs).substr(-2, 2) + ":" + ("00" + mins).substr(-2, 2);
  }

  var processShift = function(start, end, breaks) {
    return formatMinutesTo24Hr(getPaidShiftLength(start, end, breaks));
  }

  return {
    processShift: processShift
  }

})();

function startRun() {
  var breaks = [];
  breaks.push(document.getElementById('MealsTimeMonday'));
  var start = document.getElementById('StartTimeMonday');
  var end = document.getElementById('FinishTimeMonday');
  var total = document.getElementById('MondayTotal');
  total.innerHTML = timeCardManager.processShift(start, end, breaks);
}
```

```css
table {
  color: #333;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}
th {
  background: #F3F3F3;
  font-weight: bold;
}
td {
  background: #FAFAFA;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="">StartTime</th>
    <th id="">FinishTime</th>
    <th id="">MealTime</th>
    <th id="">Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="StartTimeMonday">6:00 AM</td>
    <td id="FinishTimeMonday">6:00 PM</td>
    <td id="MealsTimeMonday">0:30</td>
    <td id="MondayTotal"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btnStart">Start</button>
```

Comment: a snippet please ? (I want to try :P )

Comment: Nice one, a bit too much line for me but better for perf, here is your +1 ;)